Having difficulty with capturing the location of a geometry in geometry nodes in order to have it delete points in proximity

This setup perfectly removes geometry in proximity to the empty, which is an external object I've brought into the node tree with the object info
Now I wish to be able to do this removal but using the location of the placeholder node. I can't do this because it doesn't have an easy-to-access location output like the object info does, so I tried figuring out how attribute capture works but to no avail.
Does anyone knows how I may be able to capture the location attribute of the placeholde?


Well, it does not have a location output because the location of an external object is basically its origin rather than the positions of the individual vertices. An object generated within Geometry Nodes does not have its own origin though. It is usually placed at the origin of the base object, so the local (0, 0, 0) position and then maybe translated by an offset or instanced on the positions of some points. So the location is either (0, 0, 0), a given offset or a point's position. Reading any of these will give you the location.
